# ipykernel error while using jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I am learning Python through a course written in Jupyter notebook. In a very simple example (below) I am constantly getting the following error (also when I run the code from terminal I get the same error). When my wife runs the code in her computer, it works completely fine. We are both using Python 2.7 and same version of Jupyter.

I have no idea how to solve this problem.

```
name = input("Please enter your last name.")
sex = input("What is your sex: F/M?").lower()


if sex == "m": # male case
    print("Mr. " + name)
    #print(f"Mr. {name}") #advanced option

else: # female case
    age = int(input("Please enter your age."))
    if age < 18: # young female
        print("Miss " + name)
    else:
        name_partner = input("Please enter the last name of your    partner. Type N for no partner.")
        if name_partner != "n": # married
            print("Mrs. " + name_partner)
        else: # unknown/no marital status
            print("Ms. " + name)
```

[image: screenshot of the error message]

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an error in your configuration of ipykernel and jupyter notebook.
I recommend running this in your terminal. `conda update ipykernel jupyter`. If you are not using anaconda use `pip install ipykernel -U` and `pip install jupyter -U`.

Your code works fine in my setup.

[image]